# Moving Users between OU's in Active directory and User Profile Sync

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service

Currently we are going through a process of moving our users from one active directory OU to another OU within the same forest.

The issue that is now becoming apparent is that the users that have been moved aren't being sync'd with the user profile sync service, and thus, being removed from the user profile database and all their associated data within mysites etc, being lost!

The new OU seems to be selected for syncing within the service, as well as the old OU

At the moment the sync service is set to incremental sync

Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: Can you please share your findings? Even I have changed the OU and lost the user profiles... Were you able to get the user profile data ? Thanks
Ajay Sawant

Comment: What was the solution to the problem. I am having the exactly same issue in my environment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, you can prevent MySite deletion by disabling the MySite Cleanup Job.  Validate that the user sync'ing the OU has Replicate Directory Changes on the new target OU.

Comment: Had a word with out network guys and checked AD, the service account has 'Replicate Directory Changes' checked for the whole AD. Just waiting going to wait on the sync over the weekend and see what happens, will report back then

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the synchronization connection, you probably restricted it to a specific OU. This is not a big deal to fix (outside of the deletion of mysites, of course!).

Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications

Find your User Profile Service application, click it (I usually save this in favorites on the Central Admin front page).

Synchronization -> Configuration Synchronization Connections

Select the connection for your domain, Edit.

Type the password for your profile sync account into the password boxes, and hit Populate Containers. Verify that you have the right OUs selected for this synchronization connection. You'll probably want to leave the connection on the old OU so that you don't inadvertently kill off profiles/mysites for users that haven't been moved yet, if that applies.

Comment: One note that I discovered the hard way - Don't try to set up multiple connections to the same domain in order to encapsulate different OUs in different connections - it doesn't work. You can only have one connection per domain.